# Same algorithm in c++ and python but different output

Tags: c++, python

C++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
unsigned long long int t,n,i,m,su,s,k;
int main()
{
        cin>>n;
        if(n==0)
        {
            cout<<"0\n";
            return 0;
        }
        m = sqrt(n);
        su = m*(m+1)/2;
        s = n-1;
        for(i=2;i*i<=n;i++)
        {
            k = n/i;
            s = s + (k-1)*i + k*(k+1)/2 - su;
        }
        cout<<s<<"\n";
}
```

Python

```
import math
n = int(input())
if n==0:
    print('0')
else:
    m = int(math.sqrt(n))
    su = int(m*(m+1)/2)
    s = n-1
    i=2
    while i*i<=n:
        k = int(n/i)
        s = s + ((k-1)*i) + int(k*(k+1)/2) - su
        i = i+1
    print(s)
```

answer coming different for 1000000000
for c++ code output = 322467033612360628
for python code output = 322467033612360629
why are the answers different?
I don't think it is caused by overflow in c++ integer because in a 64 bit environment range of unsigned long long int is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

Edit :removed the variable t it was creating confusion

Comment: What version of python are you using? When I run your python code with python 2.7 I get `322467033612360628` which matches your c++ output.

Comment: Python 2.7.3 and Python 3.2.3 give different answers.

Comment: the version is Python 3.2.3

Comment: This expression: `s = 125000001750008744 + ((333333333-1)*3) + int(333333333*(333333333+1)/2) - 499991253` yields different results in python2 and python3.

Comment: *Edit :removed the variable t it was creating confusion* - A good reason to always provide the *simplest* program that recreates the problem. See http://SSCCE.ORG/.

Comment: You are having accuracy problems.  When `n` is 2, an `unsigned long` is used to receive a floating point value.  The `sqrt(2)` is not an integral value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to the [change in the division operator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) in Python 3 vs Python 2.

In Python 2, the `/` is integer floor division if both numerator and denominator are integers:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86882M, Nov 30 2010, 10:35:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 2/3
0
>>> 2.0/3.0
0.6666666666666666
>>> 
>>> 1/2 == 1.0 / 2.0
False
```

Notice that in Python 2, if either numerator or denominator are floats, the result will be a float.

But Python 3 changes the `/` to be 'True Division' and you need to use `//` to get integer floor division:

```
Python 3.3.2 (default, May 21 2013, 11:50:47) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 2/3
0.6666666666666666
>>> 2//3
0
>>> 1/2 == 1.0/2.0
True
>>> 1//2 == 1.0/2.0
False
```

C++ uses floor division between integers:

```
int main()
{
    int n=2;
    int d=3;
    cout<<n/d;    // 0
}
```

If I run this code (adapted from yours):

```
from __future__ import print_function

import math
n = 1000000000
if n==0:
    print('0')
else:
    m = int(math.sqrt(n))
    su = int(m*(m+1)/2)
    s = n-1
    i=2
    while i*i<=n:
        k = int(n/i)
        s = s + ((k-1)*i) + int(k*(k+1)/2) - su
        i = i+1
    print(s)
```

Under Python 3 I get:

```
322467033612360629
```

Under Python 2 I get:

```
322467033612360628
```

If you change this line:

`s = s + ((k-1)*i) + int(k*(k+1)/2) - su`

to

`s = s + ((k-1)*i) + int(k*(k+1)//2) - su    # Note the '//'`

it will fix the problem under Python 3